# wp_mail breaking in loop

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp

I need to send a daily email containing updated site content to about 200 users. The way I've set it up is to send one email to every 20 users (all BCC'd), so only about 10 total emails get sent. I'm using the Wordpress wp_mail() function to do the sending along with the WP-Mail-SMTP plugin so that emails are sent using a pre-configured gmail account. Everything was working fine until about a week ago. Now, all of a sudden the script breaks after 5 emails are sent.

```
//SEND THE EMAIL TO 20 USERS AT A TIME
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        array_push($mailgroup, $user->user_email);
        if(count($mailgroup) == 20) {
            $headers = $headersBase . 'Bcc: '. implode(',', $mailgroup);
            wp_mail('', 'Email Update', $strBody, $headers);
            $sentEmailCount++;
            $headers = '';
            $mailgroup = array();
        }
        $sentUserCount++;
    }
```

I believe the reason for this is that an email address in the final message sent is getting bounced and then for whatever reason the loop stops. Is there a way to disregard any errors and just continue looping regardless of whether the email message bounces or not?

Comment: Assuming that wp_mail will be breaking just put it in a try catch or just suppress is with an `@` sign...

Comment: If it's causing the script to stop then it should be logging an error - why don't you know what that error is? Also, even without the error, your code will fail to send any email to the last group of recipients unless it's a multiple of 20.

Comment: @symcbean: I'm running a script using the wp_schedule_event() method. It runs each night in the background and it sends emails to a large number of users. I can't really test it without sending the emails which would annoy my end users. How would I trap the error and log it? Would a try/catch work here with wp_mail? I've added "error_reporting(0)" to the beginning of the script in an effort to ignore errors and I'm planning on seeing what happens tonight. Thoughts? PS: I send one final email in my script post-loop in case there are more addresses.

Comment: well...the "error_reporting(0)" didn't work. loop still bombs.

Comment: No error_logging() shouldn't have *any* impact - adding a try/catch isn't going to help - if a fatal error is occurring it won't be caught. Suggest you go read the manual chapter on error handling in the PHP manual

Comment: I think I'm bumping up against some email send quota. I'm now using Mandrill for emailing. Let's see what happens tonight.

Comment: Yup...using Mandrill makes everything work. Dang quotas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ended up being an issue with bumping into a quota set by gmail for outgoing emails. I was using a plugin that set the wp_mail() function to use an SMTP account for outgoing mail. In my case I was using a gmail account. It looks as if gmail does not allow more than 100 outgoing messages to be sent within a certain period of time. I am sending 1 email to every 20 users (all users bcc'd) in each email. I only made it through the email loop 5 times (100 users) before it bombed. Damn gmail.

The fix for me was to set up a Mandrill.com account (free), install the Mandrill Wordpress plugin (free), configure it, and that's it. Now my wp_mail() function uses Mandrill to send messages and there does not seem to be a limit. No modifications to my script were required.